# How do I catch error which is instance of logging analytics in google?

Tags: react-native, error-handling, google-analytics

I have a react native project, where user can post a review and then I want to be able to log his/hers review in google analytics.

I have a problem with catching the error from google analytics. Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
const uploadReview = async () => {
    try {
      setSaving(true);
      await saveReview(id, rating);
      setSaving(false);
      navigation.goBack();
      await analytics().logEvent("log_review", {reviewId: id, rating: rating});
    } catch (error) {
      setSaving(false);
      setError("Could not submit review.");
      console.log("error while uploading review: ", error);
    }
  };
```

Right now, the way I have written my method, I might have errors in two cases:

1. While calling `saveReview` method - which is OK. If I have an error there, of course, I want to be able to show an error message to the user and say "Hey, we could not submit your review";
2. While calling `analytics().logEvent` - not cool, of course, I want to log the error, however, I don't want to display an error message to the user saying `we could not save your review`, which is not correct.

What is the correct approach in this situation? I somehow masked this behaviour by calling `navigation.goBack()` which is again not technical solution to the problem.

Comment: Split it into two separate `try/catch` blocks